# Parallel resonant circuit problem

Tags: bandwidth

[image]Before I start, YES this is for homework so I dont expect a full answer.

Just a pointer to the right method would be helpful.

I have a parallel resonant circuit. My known value is the value of the Capacitor. The unknowns are Q, L, and Fo.

The aim is to calculate BW.

Maybe Ive lost me mind, but I do not know how to do this without at least the resonant frequency, or Q. (If i had either it wouldnt be an issue to work out)

Does anyone have any practical advice on how to approach this problem please?

EDIT: I have both source and load resistances, so I can calculate equivalent R, but I am lost in how to calculate Q, L, or F.

BTW thanks. the 1st reply makes total sense to me. ill go and have another look.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief run down of the formula that apply to RLC tuned circuits: -

[image]

Shown above are: -

1. Series RLC
2. Parallel RLC
3. L and R in series, C in parallel
4. R and C in parallel, L in series

For the first two examples you can calculate \$\omega_0\$ but for the last two examples you need to know the loss and this is due to R. However, the lossless value of \$\omega_0\$ is a reasonable approximation.

For all examples, the 3dB bandwidth of the filter can only be calculated knowing what R is.

Information taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit).

Comment: Agreed, but I do not have angular freq or the value of L.

I do have input and output R, and the Value of C. thats all.

Comment: Show the circuit you do have and include all the information. What I've stated holds true and if you don't have L then you can only calculate bandwidth formulaicly.

Comment: Image loaded. I agree, only a ratio would be possible. Hence my confusion lol